# Who said that I prefer to keep an air of mystery about myself and why?

Tags: support, profile-page

Who and why did someone say about me "Apparently, this user prefers to keep an air of mystery about them." referring to me? FYI - I forgot this place was here. I posted once about the mass of photons (which is described in Feynman lectures bty).

Comment: FWIW, that text you're referencing is boiler plate text inserted into everyone's profile until they edit it to be something else.

Comment: Maybe a question for [meta.se]? The answer is pretty obvious: it's SE's fun way of indicating that you haven't written an about-me thing and hence you don't want to tell people about yourself.

Comment: @Chair Although the question is ontopic (and a better match) on the MSE, I think it is ontopic also here.

Comment: @Chair With things like these, migration or cross-posting to MSE should be preceded with a search for duplicates there, which already exist in most simple cases. As for this being "fun" - different people have different ideas about that, and not everybody appreciates SE putting words in their mouth.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty Yeah, the similar post on the main meta brings up the opinion that those could be  insulting stuff, and somebody asks for a feature to turn it off and replace it with more generic sentences.

Answer (score 8):

It's a boilerplate template for all users across all Stack Exchange sites. Once you edit your profile, that language is replaced with whatever you wrote in there.

See [this Meta.SE post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/251810/230312) or [this Meta.SO post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/290394/1276356) for more details.